# Eclipse Platform Upgrade Issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to upgrade Eclipse platform for RCP product from 4.6.3 to 4.15. I see that org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ImageAndMessageArea class is removed from the Eclipse 4.15 and code using it resulted in compilation error: "ImageAndMessageArea can not be resolved to a type".

I searched the issue on google and found couple of links that are pointing to Bugzilla bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475863 which says this class is marked for deletion and is removed but no information is provided on how to replace this class with other class.

May I know what is the replacement for org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ImageAndMessageArea in Eclipse 4.15 so that I can resolve compilation error with same functionality.

Comment: That had been deprecated since Eclipse 3.3 so you really shouldn't have been using it. I don't believe there is a direct replacement.

Comment: Please read the _Plug-in Migration Guide_ which also covers the removal of ImageAndMessageArea from JFace in Eclipse 4.11 (with a link to the bug for details): https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/porting/removals.html